# JQuery одинаковые названия классов

Tags: jquery

У меня есть 2 кнопки и для них прописан один и тот же псевдокласс after ( иконка в виде изображения ). С помощью JQuery делаю вращение этой иконки при нажатии на кнопку. Но проблема в том, что вращаются иконки для двух кнопок... Как сделать, чтобы вращалась только конкретная иконка у той кнопка, которая нажата?

```
$($btn).click(function() {
    $('.personal-account-tables table').toggleClass('border-bottom-table');
    $('.personal-account-tables tr th button:first-child').after(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('rotate-block');
    });
  });
```

Вот кнопки

```
<button class="uk-width-1-6@m btn-tariff-select btn-show-tariff-table" type="button">Сравнить тарифы</button>

    <button class="uk-width-1-6@m btn-tariff-select btn-show-tariff-table" type="button">Сравнить тарифы</button>
```

Вот стили для изображения внутри кнопки

```
button {
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;

    &:after {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 0 0 15px;
        content: url('../lk-arrow.svg');
        transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    }
    &.rotate-block:after {
        padding: 0 15px 0 0;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    &:hover:after {
        content: url('../lk-arrow-white.svg');
    }
}
```

Comment: добавьте верстку к вопросу пожалуйста

Comment: Ухх, боюсь сюда вся не влезет...

Comment: @ВикторТюрин достаточно 2х этих кнопок

Comment: а вы только часть где эти кнопки и элементы которые участвуют в анимации и в скрипте

Comment: подправил сообщение

Comment: Зачем тут jQuery? Вам ховера мало?

Comment: @DaemonHK Потому что нужно сделать rotate при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: @ВикторТюрин угу, понял... Пляшите относительно родителя - найдите все дочерние таблицы, а затем типа - **$('.parent').find('table').each(function(){ //ваша функция });**

Comment: var $btn = $('.btn-show-tariff-table'); $btn.each(function() { //сюда код для ротейта. this в этом контексте будет указывать на кнопку по которой кликнули})

Comment: Спасибо, щас буду пробовать. Если получится, отпишу

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WVOLvP - не оно? в коде елементов не хватает правда, не вижу стрелки, которая крутится должна

Comment: @Taarim content: url('../lk-arrow.svg'); потому что я локально указал)

Comment: @Taarim <svg width="14" height="8" viewBox="0 0 14 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d="M12.0103 1.25684L6.50494 6.74255L0.999931 1.25684" stroke="#F2994A" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>

Comment: Сделал с кнопками))) а как сделать так, чтобы рамка для таблицы добавлялась к конкретной таблице, а не для двух сразу?

Comment: В код пене таблицу всю добавьте в верстке и ссылку оставьте

Comment: @Taarim https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZgyVZL

Comment: @Taarim получается, когда нажимаем на кнопку, класс добавляется, когда нажимаем на вторую кнопку, класс удаляется. Это нормально, но так должно быть для одной таблицы, а не для двух сразу... Еще не разобрался с этим(

Comment: строка 5-10 https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QegYbN

Comment: @Taarim работает! Спасибо большое! Никогда бы не догадался сам)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае требовалось помимо прокрутки самой кнопки, дополнительно менять класс для таблицы родителя.

Вопрос решился следующим кодом:

```
function toggleCatalogBlock($btn, $block) {

  $($btn).click(function() {
    var $button = $(this), 
        $table = $button.closest('.personal-account-tables table');

    $(this).toggleClass('rotate-block'); //прокрутка текущей кнопки

    $table.toggleClass('border-bottom-table'); // добавление класса к родителю
};
```

Часть кода опущена из функции т.к. не имеет отношения к решению задачи. Полный код примера можно найти [тут](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QegYbN)